# How to bulk insert using Spring-Batch?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-batch and spring-data-jpa to read large csv data files and persist (or update existing) entries to a postgresql db using hibernate.

How do I have to configure spring to make using of batch/bulk inserts?

When I configure the job `step`, I set the `chunk` size accordingly:

```
StepBuilderFactory step;
step.chunk(10000).reader(csvReader).writer(jpaItemWriter).build();
```

Do I further have to be concerned about the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` property? Do I have to also set it, maybe to the same size as the chunk size?

Comment: I have been doing some research with the batch insert for some times. But with my limited information i can say that. You can actually send a set of Query together. But not a query will a set of information together. ie; there will be multiple insert query but the turnaround time will be less.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the chunk size then your reader will send data to the writer in specified chunks. so the chunk size is what governs the actual batch update to the db in spring batch.

I don't think batch_size matters as you have already setup your job for a specific chunk size for a particular step.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use the Bulk Update query when writing to the database. Google [JDBC Bulk updates](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jdbc%20bulk%20update&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8vaLVIK2DMKVuATZv4HABA) for details  - so depending on how you are doing the JDBC query you will need to use the corresponding bulk update mechanism

Comment: Yes but the question was: how can I achieve bulk updates with `hibernate` (that is used by spring-batch)?

Comment: ooops ok - sorry I don't know the answer to that

Answer (score 0):

Can you write those records into a temp file and load it using native db command to load into the table instead of Hibernate? I've used it in the past even though we used Hibernate and found it performing very well.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."